# How to make a web browser's type as a web browser

Tags: android, eclipse, browser, defaults

I currently have made my own web browser with the android SDK in eclipse, BUT when I use my app, in settings it is not letting me set this browser as a default browser or if I click a link on the google app it will give me the message "open in" and my app is not there. Is there anything I need to put in my code to tell android that my app is a web browser? Here is my manifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rarster.QuantumBrowser"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="21" android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
         <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
          <activity
            android:name=".SocialNetwork"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
             <activity
            android:name=".Home2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
                <activity
            android:name=".Note"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
                  <activity
            android:name=".News"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
                  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
                   <activity
            android:name=".Intro"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What have you given in your manifest file, for the activity you have designed as a browser

Comment: No where you have mentioned in the Manifest file that your activity is capable of being a browser. Below if the manifest property of android browser. Hope this helps.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: My question was, how do I tell android that it is capable of being a browser, my app has the functionality of a browser but I don't know what to put in my manifest to tell android its a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything I need to put in my code to tell android that my app is a web browser?

You need an `<intent-filter>` (or several) that supports Web browsing. Check out the `BrowserActivity` entry in [the AOSP Browser app's manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml) to see how they handle it and determine what will match the capabilities that your app offers.